# Multiplying an Enum in C++

Tags: c++, quantlib

I have some code that is multiplying an enum by an integer:

```
QuantLib::Date date2 = date + 12 * QuantLib::Months;
```

Where QuantLib::Months is defined as:

```
enum TimeUnit { Days,
                Weeks,
                Months,
                Years
};
```

This gives me the desired result of *date2* being one year on from *date*. However, I'm not able to comprehend how this is being achieved.

I had thought that this would not compile. Now I feel that I'm arriving at a "twelve months" object, which the is then handled by the QuantLib::Date '+' operator overload, but I've never seen this style before.

I have come from a C# background, so there may be something I'm not aware of at work here. Can anyone explain what is going on? Any reference documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing strange both in enum implicit conversion and operator overloading. You'd better check all the code involved because Months indeed are converted to 2 and although you may see result date2 was increased for 1 year but the way how it was achieved may contain some surprises

Comment: Don't believe quants - they usually are smart guys but allow dirty tricks. I've just realised that those guys overloaded operator* for enum TimeUnit - nice joke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the following is in effect here:

1. In C++, an enumeration type can be implicitly converted to an integral type. If this is happening here, `date + 12 * QuantLib::Months` would be the same as `date + 12 * 2`.
2. It is also possible to overload operators for enumeration types. In that case, it might be that the library defines an `operator* (int, QuantLib::TimeUnit)` which returns something compatible with the `+` you're doing.

I don't know `QuantLib`, but I'd guess #2 is what's happening. [QuantLib documentation](http://quantlib.org/reference/namespace_quant_lib.html#a26a1ae8ba98b630db20bbf8e3cb84dfc) corroborates this (thanks to @DaliborFrivaldsky for the link).

Comment: but the OP has quoted a definition of the enum type without any operator overloading which seems to rule out 2. ?

Comment: It must be the second item, as if I use date + 12 * 2, I get a different result to date + 12 * QuantLib::Lib.

Comment: It' the case number 2 - http://quantlib.org/reference/namespace_quant_lib.html , search for TimeUnit and the second reference found is a declaration of Template< typename T >  Period operator* (T n, TimeUnit units)

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths How can you know whether an operator is overloaded or not from looking at the definition of an enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all enumerations are basically integer constants, and as all integer values you can use them in arithmetic expressions.

In your case the constant `QuantLib::Months` has the value `2`, as enumerations starts from zero and are simply increased.

---

However, unless you *have* to make your own data/time functionality, I suggest you use the functionality available in [the standard library `<chrono>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (or [Boost chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono.html) if you don't have a C++11 capable compiler/library). It has all this functionality built-in.

Here is an example similar to your code

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();  // The current time at the moment
auto then = now + std::chrono::hours(24 * 365);
```

The variable `then` will now be a [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) `24 * 365` hours in the future from `now`.

Comment: This would imply that, if I replaced my code with date2 = date + 24, I would arrive at the same result? But I don't.

Comment: QuantLib runs right through this codebase, so I'll be working with it for the time being.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg There is no such default rule in C++. Enumerators have type that is the underlying type of the enumeration.

Comment: I agree with @VladfromMoscow Just because `enum` variables appear on one system with an integral value that you can use to perform math, does not mean they will on every system.

Comment: @DavidWilkins Well, not really. They are not of type `int`, but they are guaranteed to implicitly convert to an integral type, and the resulting value is also specified by the standard.

Comment: this is not technically correct but in general acceptable answer

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using a so-called unscoped enumeration. Each enumeration has an underlying integral type (that is not necessary the type `int` There is no such a default rule for enumerations in C++).
According to paragraph 4.5.3 of the C++ Standard (you asked some reference to documentation):

> 3 A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   not fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the
>   following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration
>   (i.e., the values in the range bmin to bmax as described in 7.2): int,
>   unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned
>   long long int. If none of the types in that list can represent all the
>   values of the enumeration, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type
>   can be converted to a prvalue of the extended integer type with lowest
>   integer conversion rank (4.13) greater than the rank of long long in
>   which all the values of the enumeration can be represented. If there
>   are two such extended types, the signed one is chosen.

So in your example `QuantLib::Months` is converted to int because all values of the enumeration can be stored in an object of type int. Then usual arithmetic conversions are performed in the multiplicative operation.